# How Do I Construct The Following Query in Grafana?

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I'd like to create a query variable in Grafana that will bring back a series a distinct **Host Names** that will be used to filter out results in my dashboard.

I am using ElasticSearch as the datasource and here is a sample of the fields in the log record(showing only the host:hostname for brevity):

```
   "host": {
      "hostname": "ip-xx-xx-xx-xx",
      "architecture": "x86_64",
    }
```

The term "**host.hostname**" is what I am trying to retrieve.

In the table view of ElasticSearch the field is displayed as follows:

[image: Table View of host.hostname field]

Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. I want to write a Lucene query for a Grafana query variable.
2. For the time-range that the user selects I'd like the query to return all available hosts in the current ElasticSearch stream.
3. **I'd like to return only unique entries**.  If the stream contains 3 unique hosts I'd like to return only 3.
4. This query variable will be used in the dashboard to filter out specific hosts (one, multiple or all) and then I'd like my panel queries to display results only for the hosts that the user has selected.

Here is the query I currently have, not surprisingly, it doesn't work:

```
{"find": "terms", "field": "host.hostname", "query": "ip-*"}
```

Here is what the Variable Edit screen looks like (Datasource name scrubbed):
[image]

Here is what the panel editor looks like. Not that ip addresses are shown in legend.  That's fine. In this case I'm trying to display the "actual free" memory.  Note that no data is displayed (another newbie issue).

[image]

I'm brand new to ElasticSearch with Grafana so my attempt I'm sure looks lame to more experienced folks.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**I am using the 7.5.0-beta Docker image.**